# Tomcat configuration to accept HTTPS on a different Port

Tags: java, tomcat7

My Tomcat 7 is running on Port 4545. How do I configure it to accept HTTPS connection on 4546 or something else. I can't have it on default 443 as there is already IIS running.

**UPDATE**

Steps I tried out:

1. My 8443 port is already used by Plesk.
2. I replaced 8443 with 4546 in the XML file and uncommented the line as in tutorial.
3. Then I added a firewall exception for the PORT but still it doesn't load.
4. It shows timeout message after sometime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In *tomcatDir*/conf/server.xml look for this line:

```
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

It is self-explanatory, just take into account that you also need to have certificates in order for SSL to work properly.

Also, have a look at its documentation that explains how to specify your certificates: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html

Comment: @akhil Could you post the exception that ur getting?

Comment: Ok, this is not going to be easy... in order for this to be quickier and improve your question, try answering these questions: Which type of certificates you have? certificates bought from a CA? auto-signed certificates generated with OpenSSL, Windows CA or java's tool "keytool"? do you have the Apache Portable Runtime Library installed? all this is important

Comment: @morgano hey it was an error with xml. spelling mistak while copy paste. well that was a self signed one. thanks.